# how do I change facility in glog from the default user facility?

Tags: syslog, glog

I see that glog messages are getting logged with 'user' facility. Where does it set and how do I change it dynamically from my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command line to set glog

```
./your_application --logtostderr=1
```

The official document has a complete introduction [link](https://github.com/google/glog#setting-flags)